# How do I use data binding for custom attributes in Android when the attribute format is "reference"?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a custom attribute defined as follows:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomView">
 <attr name="customimage" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

The attribute should be a reference to a drawable. It works fine if I do this:

```
app:customimage="@drawable/customimagename"
```

But I am trying to use Android data binding to dynamically set the image. And I can't seem to set this attribute with a field from my viewmodel.

Here is what I've tried so far where `viewmodel.imageResourceId` is the resource id integer for the drawable:

```
app:customimage="@{viewmodel.imageResourceId}"
app:customimage="@{ContextCompat.getColor(context, viewmodel.imageResourceId)}"
```

I've also tried passing it a drawable where `viewmodel.imageDrawable` is the actual drawable:

```
app:customimage="@{viewmodel.imageDrawable}"
```

I also tried creating a `BindingAdapter` to set the value. But none of these even compiles. So how do I pass a reference for a drawable to a custom attribute using data binding?

Comment: android BindingAdapter is exactly what you want, I think your problem is in implementation it.  How exactly you want to set image? with resource id? or file url?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you very much. I was trying to get the BindingAdapter to assign a `reference` instead of actually assigning the drawable. Problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: @user2625768 I'm wondering. How did you write your BindingAdapter actually?